# HTML Application Cache expiry

Tags: html, ipad, application-cache

I've been asked to build offline access to some content that I've been working on, & was just wondering... Does the cache expire at all, & if so, is it after a certain duration, or dependant on device?

My main focus for this is the iPad, if it makes a difference.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The cache can expire for a number of reasons:

- A request for the manifest file returns an HTTP status 404 response
- The user chooses to delete the cache through the browser's UI
- There is some system related storage issue (eg. system cleans up old files to free space, or some sort of device reset)